# Scala: Why the class of an Array object is "[I" when calling getClass()?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have the following codes:

```
 val myarray = Array(888, 999)
    println(myarray)
    println(myarray.getClass)
```

The result is:

```
[I@2715644a
class [I
```

This is strange. Shouldn't it be `Array[Int]` type? What is `[I`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is Java's default `toString` implementation. Since `Array` doesn't have a nice `toString`, it's defaulting to it.

The `[I` is denoting an array of Integers, and the number after the `@` sign is the hashcode.